# Heroku - Clojure App using Stuart Sierra Component Error in "main"

Tags: heroku, clojure

I am trying to start my clojure application on my heroku dyno but I keep getting and error in my stuartsierra.component/start.

```
(defrecord Listener [listener]
  component/Lifecycle
  (start [component]
    (assoc component :listener (yada/listener
                                 ["/"
                                  [(view/view-route)
                                   routes/route-handler
                                   ["public/" (new-directory-resource (io/file "target/cljsbuild/public") {})]
                                   [true (as-resource nil)]]]
                                 (or (env :port) (get (read-config "resources/config.edn" {:profile :dev}) :webserver))
                                 )))
  (stop [component]
    (when-let [close (-> component :listener :close)]
      (close))
    (assoc component :listener nil)))

(defn new-system []
  (component/system-map
    :listener (map->Listener {})
    ))

(def system nil)

(defn init []
  (alter-var-root #'system
                  (constantly (new-system))))

(defn start []
  (alter-var-root #'system component/start))

(defn stop []
  (alter-var-root #'system
                  (fn [s] (when s (component/stop s)))))

(defn go []
  (init)
  (start))

(defn reset []
  (stop)
  (refresh :after 'web.core/go))

(defn -main
  [& [port]]
  (component/start (new-system))
  (println "System Started")
  @(promise))
```

This is my core file with all my stuartsierra.component code. This all works perfectly when I run it locally on my laptop doing `lein repl` and then `(go)` and also when I just do `lein run`. So I am confused as to why it doesn't work when I push this to the heroku dyno.

The error I get is

```
Exception in thread "main" clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Error in component :listener in system com.stuartsierra.component.SystemMap calling #'com.stuartsierra.component/start {:reason :com.stuartsierra.component/component-function-threw-exception, :function #'com.stuartsierra.component/start, :system-key :listener, :component #web.core.Listener{:listener nil}, :system #<SystemMap>}, compiling:(/tmp/form-init9049917434081554913.clj:1:73)
```

This is telling me that my `:listener` is `nil` in the `system-map`. When I check locally (doing `lein repl` `(go)`) in `(keys system)` is `(:listener)` which is good so that means that the listener is starting and is in the system.

When I do `(-> system :listener)` I get `#web.core.Listener{:listener {:port 3300, :close #object[yada.aleph$listener$fn__21671 0xa5d4865 "yada.aleph$listener$fn__21671@a5d4865"], :server #object[aleph.netty$start_server$reify__13574 0x3cc9a232 "aleph.netty$start_server$reify__13574@3cc9a232"]}}` which is perfect as the port has loaded up (3300) and the server has started.

This makes it all the more confusing as to why the `:listener` is `nil` in my heroku app

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What does your `Procfile` look like? Can you run locally with `heroku local web`?

Comment: @codefinger My `Procfile` is `web: lein with-profile production trampoline run -m web.core`. If I do `heroku local web` I get `[WARN] No ENV file found`

Comment: @codefinger I have been trying to add an ENV file but I thought all the ENV properties were in the config?

Comment: That is strange. What happens if you add another explicit port to the `listener` i.e. `(or (env :port) (get (read-config "resources/config.edn" {:profile :dev}) :webserver) {:port 3300})`.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku dynamically assigns ports to `web:` processes.  The value of that port should be passed to the Clojure code using the Heroku environment variable `$PORT`

So the Procfile should include the port variable

```
web: lein with-profile production trampoline run -m web.core $PORT
```

This port value should be passed into the component from the `-main` function in the `web.core` namespace.

As Heroku will build an uberjar (your Clojure application + Clojure itself) if the `:uberjar-name "webapp.jar"` and  `:min-lein-version "2.0.0"` settings are included in `project.clj` file.

The java command can then be used to run the Clojure application, using the uberjar that Heroku builds and using fewer resources

```
web: java -jar target/webapp.jar $PORT
```

Reference:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#the-web-process-type
- https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/sample.project.clj